# Select Multiple Fields from List in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

In ASP.NET C# I have a struct:

```
public struct Data
{
    public int item1;
    public int item2;
    public int category_id;
    public string category_name;
}
```

and I have a List of those.  I want to select `category_id` and `category_name`, running a `DISTINCT` and finally an `ORDERBY` on `category_name`.

Here's what I have now:

```
List<Data> listObject = getData();
string[] catNames = listObject
                    .Select(i=> i.category_name)
                    .Distinct()
                    .OrderByDescending(s => s)
                    .ToArray();
```

This obviously just gets the category name.  My question is, how do I get multiple fields, and what data structure will I store this in (not a `string[]`)?

EDIT

Using a list of structs is not set in stone.  If it would be advisable to change my backing data structure to make selects easier (I'll be writing a lot of these) then I'd gladly take recommendations.

Comment: While it's unrelated to the LINQ side, I would *strongly* advise you not to use mutable structs or public fields. Personally I rarely create structs in the first place, but mutable structs are just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks.  I'll convert it to a regular class with private members.

Comment: @Midhat: Mutable structs cause all kinds of problems, as they don't behave as people expect them to. And public fields give a complete lack of encapsulation.

Comment: @Jon Skeet. Can you be more specific with the pitfalls of mutable structs, or point me to a reading.

Comment: @Midhat: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil for a starting point.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

Anonymous types allow you to select arbitrary fields into data structures that are strongly typed later on in your code:

```
var cats = listObject
    .Select(i => new { i.category_id, i.category_name })
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.category_name)
    .ToArray();
```

Since you (apparently) need to store it for later use, you could use the GroupBy operator:

```
Data[] cats = listObject
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.category_id, i.category_name })
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key.category_name)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I want to use distinct on 1 column and retrieve multiple columns.SO how can i do it?

Comment: I never thought to `Select` into a new type. In my case I selected into a new `KeyValuePair`.

Answer (score 31):

You could use an anonymous type:

```
.Select(i => new { i.name, i.category_name })
```

The compiler will generate the code for a class with `name` and `category_name` properties and returns instances of that class. You can also manually specify property names:

```
i => new { Id = i.category_id, Name = i.category_name }
```

You can have arbitrary number of properties.

Comment: I wish I knew this years ago. Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

```
var selectedCategories =
    from value in
        (from data in listObject
        orderby data.category_name descending
        select new { ID = data.category_id, Name = data.category_name })
    group value by value.Name into g
    select g.First();

foreach (var category in selectedCategories) Console.WriteLine(category);
```

**Edit**: Made it more LINQ-ey!

Answer (score 14):

You can select multiple fields using linq Select as shown above in various examples this will return as an Anonymous Type. If you want to avoid this anonymous type here is the simple trick.

```
var items = listObject.Select(f => new List<int>() { f.Item1, f.Item2 }).SelectMany(item => item).Distinct();
```

I think this solves your problem

Comment: Your solution could be simplified by removing `Select` like so: `var items = listObject.SelectMany(f => new List<int>() { f.Item1, f.Item2 }).Distinct();`

Answer (score 7):

This is task for which [*anonymous types*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) are very well suited. You can return objects of a type that is created automatically by the compiler, inferred from usage.

The syntax is of this form:

```
new { Property1 = value1, Property2 = value2, ... }
```

For your case, try something like the following:

```
var listObject = getData();
var catNames = listObject.Select(i =>
    new { CatName = i.category_name, Item1 = i.item1, Item2 = i.item2 })
    .Distinct().OrderByDescending(s => s).ToArray();
```

Comment: The additional clarification on how to name the output properties is great here, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can make it a KeyValuePair, so it will return a `"IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>"`

So, it will be like this:

```
.Select(i => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(i.category_id, i.category_name )).Distinct();
```

Comment: This adds unnecessary complexity without a benefit

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = listObject.Select( i => new{ i.category_name, i.category_id } )
```

This uses anonymous types so you must the var keyword, since the resulting type of the expression is not known in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
(from i in list
 select new { i.category_id, i.category_name })
 .Distinct()
 .OrderBy(i => i.category_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public int ID { set; get; }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student[] students =
        {
        new Student { Name="zoyeb" , ID=1},
        new Student { Name="Siddiq" , ID=2},
        new Student { Name="sam" , ID=3},
        new Student { Name="james" , ID=4},
        new Student { Name="sonia" , ID=5}
        };

        var studentCollection = from s in students select new { s.ID , s.Name};

        foreach (var student in studentCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(student.ID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given `List<MyType1> internalUsers` and `List<MyType2> externalUsers`, based on the shared key of an email address...

---

***For C# 7.0+:***

```
var matches = (
    from i in internalUsers
    join e in externalUsers
    on i.EmailAddress.ToUpperInvariant() equals e.Email.ToUpperInvariant()
    select (internalUser:i, externalUser:e)
).ToList();
```

Which gives you `matches` as a `List<(MyType1, MyType2)>`.

From there you can compare them if you wish:

```
var internal_in_external = matches.Select(m => m.internalUser).ToList();
var external_in_internal = matches.Select(m => m.externalUser).ToList();

var internal_notIn_external = internalUsers.Except(internal_in_external).ToList();
var external_notIn_internal = externalUsers.Except(external_in_internal).ToList();
```

`internal_in_external` and `internal_notIn_external` will be of type `List<MyType1>`.

`external_in_internal` and `external_notIn_internal` will be of type `List<MyType2>`

---

***For versions of C# prior to 7.0:***

```
var matches = (
    from i in internalUsers
    join e in externalUsers
    on i.EmailAddress.ToUpperInvariant() equals e.Email.ToUpperInvariant()
    select new Tuple<MyType1, MyType2>(i, e)
).ToList();
```

Which gives you `matches` as a `List<Tuple<MyType1, MyType2>>`.

From there you can compare them if you wish:

```
var internal_in_external = matches.Select(m => m.Item1).ToList();
var external_in_internal = matches.Select(m => m.Item2).ToList();

var internal_notIn_external = internalUsers.Except(internal_in_external).ToList();
var external_notIn_internal = externalUsers.Except(external_in_internal).ToList();
```

`internal_in_external` and `internal_notIn_external` will be of type `List<MyType1>`.

`external_in_internal` and `external_notIn_internal` will be of type `List<MyType2>`