# How to get 2 columns from datatable in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have:

```
var ids = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => (int)x["Id"]).ToList();
```

However I also need to retreive another column, name: "level" of type int also. expecting output something like:

```
var<int,int> ids = ....
```

Comment: or, since it's just `Linq-To-Objects`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202981/select-multiple-fields-from-list-in-linq

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach would be an anonymous type:

```
var ids = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
{
    Id = (int)x["Id"],
    Level = (int)x["level"]
}).ToList();
```

This will give you a `List<>` of that anonymous type, so now you could do something like this:

```
var level = ids[0].Level
```

**UPDATE:** if you're going to have to store them in `Session` for persistence then I'd recommend building a real type (`class`), let's call it `Foo` for this example. That would change the code to:

```
var ids = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Foo
{
    Id = (int)x["Id"],
    Level = (int)x["level"]
}).ToList();
```

Then when you need to get them out of `Session`:

```
var ids = (List<Foo>)Session["ids"];
```

Comment: Michael I have added ids to Session and am not able to retreive it again from the Session - i tried this: 
"var ids = (List<Tuple<Int32,Int32>>)Session["ids"]" but gives an error

Comment: @user2906420: you tried adding `ids` to `Session` and then pulling it back out?

Comment: @user2906420: please see my edit as I attempt to address the need for persistence.