# How do I group a list using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq, linq-to-entities

The scenario I have is as follows:

I have the following data -

### ID, Name, Place, Location, GroupID

```
1, samename, Grand Central, New York, 12
2, samename, Opera House, Sydney, 12
3, samename, Opera House, Sydney, 12
4, name2, Emirates, London, 13
5, name3, Opera House, Sydney, 14
```

And I would like to output it as two tables

### GroupID,Name

```
12, samename
13, name2
14, name3
```

### GroupID, Place, Location

```
Grand Central, New York, 12
Opera House, Sydney, 12
Opera House, Sydney, 12
Emirates, London, 13
Opera House, Sydney, 14
```

This was really bad design that I have inherited - and I am trying to make it better.. without breaking the old code.

Comment: Check out this article about selecting multiple items form an iEnum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202981/select-multiple-fields-from-list-in-linq

Comment: Based on this data this could also be done by simply selecting the desired columns and doing a `Distinct`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps, first group them on `Name` and `GroupID`:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>new {x.GroupID, x.Name})
                 .Select(g=> new { GroupID = g.Key.GroupID, Name = g.Key.Name});
```

and in second case group them with other three columns (`GroupID`,`Place` and `Location`):

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>new {x.GroupID, x.Location,x.Place})
                 .Select(g=> new 
                         { 
                           GroupID = g.Key.GroupID, 
                           Location = g.Key.Location, 
                           Place = x.Key.Place
                         });
```

Comment: I'd recommend to already give the names of the properties in the GroupBy and then just to `Select(g => g.Key)`

Comment: Or just a `.Select(x => new { ... }).Distinct()`